# How to disable Gnome ctrl+alt+down and ctrl+alt+up shortcut?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

There's a shortcut on Discord that enables you to switch between guilds easily. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

The problem is that Gnome uses this shortcut for changing workspaces. I have two monitors so I don't use additional workspaces very often so I opened settings and looked for the shortcut so that I can disable it.

I found that apparently the shortcut to switch workspaces up and down is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> and I couldn't find the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or down shortcut anywhere else. It seems almost as if this shortcut isn't possible to change but I'm sure that's not the case, though I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I disabled the workspace up and workspace down shortcuts (by using gnome tweak tool and hitting 'backspace' for the binding for each shortcut, and then clicking the 'Set' button -- this disables the shortcut altogether). This worked for me without having to use the dconf solutions listed below.

Comment: This can be done at `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > General` then modify `Show the window selection screen`. You can work out what the action that a shortcut carries out is called by making a custom shortcut using the same binding. It will warn you that you are replacing <name of shortcut>.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In general this can happen because the OS (window system) has priority and intercepts this shortcut and stops propagation to your desired application.
Solution: Removing the shortcuts using `dconf-editor`:

- Open a terminal
- `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` (or `dconf-editor`)
- Now run `dconf-editor`
- in dconf-editor go to: `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/`
- Find `switch-to-workspace-down`, put `['disabled']` instead of `default`
- same for `switch-to-workspace-up`
- quit `dconf-editor` and you are done

I always have this problem when I want to use some Eclipse IDE shortcuts:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321094

Comment: What is the difference between `[]` and `["disabled"]`, is it not the same ?

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up + Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Down conflict with default common VSCode shortcuts. It took an hour to find this answer, then 2 minutes to fix it using Christophe Roussy's suggestion above.

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10, there was no package called `dconf-tools`. I installed the package `dconf-editor` and everything else in this answer worked for me.

Comment: It honestly shocks me that this is still an issue, given that by default Gnome doesn't use vertical activities anymore.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked perfectly as you might expect.

Answer (score 25):

Gnome Settings shows only Super key combination for switching workspaces; even `gnome-tweak-tool` is not helpful.

Anyway, you can still open `dconf` and edit the two related keys:

from

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']
```

to

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up']
```

The same for the other key combination.

You can run these commands on the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super>Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Super><Shift>Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Super><Shift>Page_Down']"
```

Comment: unknown keyword:
  [<Super>Page_Up]

Comment: what are you saying? I don't understand

Comment: He's say that when he uses gsetting in the matter you described, it gives an error 'unknown keyword' (even though it shouldn't). I'm having the same issue and came across this thread. Got any ideas? I'm Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland.

Comment: Well, in my case, I had screwed up the double quotes: writing  ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down'] instead of  "['<Super><Shift>Page_Down']"

Answer (score 8):

Since you have two monitors and don't need workspace, I will suggest to disable the shortcuts for "Move to workspace above/below":

1. Setting > Devices > Keyboard
2. search "workspace"
3. click on "Move to workspace above", press Backspace, press Set, done.

In fact, I disabled all shortcuts related to workspace...

Comment: The only answer that works without installing anything. Works on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Then you can even add them again (Super+PgUp and Super+PgDn), and everything will work: Super+... combinations will do the job and ctrl+alt+arrow will be disabled

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Answer (score 2):

You can do it purely from the settings. That app is not designed to show all enabled options in the `dconf`, but setting `dconf` values works correctly. So you should do the following:

1. Go to "Settings" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts" (or "Settings" -> "Devices" -> "Keyboard" for earlier versions)
2. Find "Navigation" -> "Move to workspace ..."
3. Click on it, press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> (or <kbd>PgDown</kbd>), press "Set".

If it does not work, instead of step 3 remove shortcut by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and press "Set", then click on the item again and set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>, then press "Set".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install any additional package.

If you want to disable `"Switch to workspace up/down"` (in my case, it was conflicting with VSCode `"Add Cursor Below/Above"`), you can run following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['']"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable those keys in Ubuntu,

- Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts >
- SET (by click>backspace>enter):

  - Move to workspace above=Disabled
  - & Move to workspace below=Disabled

When you want to reset then there is reset option available also, so don't worry

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: This seems to be basically the same as [ys_sunshine’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445977/80216) (from 3½ years ago).

Comment: Yes, but in easily understandable way (because of image)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the selected answer but unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

I'm using **Fedora 37** with **Gnome 43 - Wayland** at the time of writing.

What worked for me was to reassign the shortcut to the very same keys *(despite being already the case)*:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Go to **Keyboard**
3. Go to **View and Customize Shortcuts**
4. Look for **Move to workspace on the left** and click on it
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or your preferred shortcut
6. Look for **Move to workspace on the right** and click on it
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or your preferred shortcut

After that, the shortcuts are modified although we're using the same key bindings.